# Youtbe API -- OAuth and RSA-SHA1 security certificate

Tags: php, api, oauth, youtube, certificate

I want to make a file upload which will upload the (uploaded) movie file to my youtube account. To my understanding, I will need a youtube API key (which I have) and then send the file to google. This is where I'm having problems. I seem to be needing a "RSA-SHA1 security certificate" to complete my OAuth registration.

How would I get such a certificate? The only documentation I can find on this matter is very hard to understand for an "api noob" like me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can appreciate the difficulty learning all the OAuth incantations.  Every time I go through it I understand it just a little bit better.  [Here's the Google note about generating RSA-SHA1 certificates.](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/authsub.html#Registered)